Solving $\lim_{y\to 1}\frac{y^2-4\sqrt{y}+3}{y^2-1}$
The problem:
$\lim_{y\to 1}\frac{y^2-4\sqrt{y}+3}{y^2-1}$
The solution:
$-\frac{1}{2}$
What I have tried:
$\lim_{y\to 1}\frac{y^2-4\sqrt{y}+3}{y-1}=\lim_{y\to 1}\frac{(y^2-4\sqrt{y}+3)(y^2+4\sqrt{y}+3)}{(y^2-1)(y^2+4\sqrt{y}+3)}=\lim_{y\to 1}\frac{y^2-(4\sqrt{y}+3)^2}{(y^2-1)(y^2+4\sqrt{y}+3)}=\lim_{y\to 1}\frac{y^2-16y-24\sqrt{y}-9}{(y+1)(y-1)(y^2+4\sqrt{y}+3)}$
My question:
How do I continue simplifying the equation to get to the solution? I don't know where to continue from here. Should I perhaps try another approach?

suggest  taking $y = x^2$  and let $x$ go to $1.$  Now you have a ratio of polynomials that both become $0$  when you just plug in $x=1.$  Thus both polynomials have a factor of $x-1,$ divide that out of both.

Is the question about $y^2-4\sqrt{y} + 3$ or $y-4\sqrt{y} + 3$? Everything about your question suggests the former but you just changed it to the latter.

I suggest leave as early $y^2-4\sqrt{y} + 3$, because below answers are written for it and create new question for $y-4\sqrt{y} + 3$.

I've edited my answer and I've solved both limits




$$\frac{y^2-4\sqrt{y}+3}{y^2-1}=\frac{y^2-\sqrt{y}-3\sqrt{y}+3}{(y-1)(y+1)}=\\
=\frac{\sqrt{y}(y^{3/2}-1)-3(\sqrt{y}-1)}{(\sqrt{y}-1)(\sqrt{y}+1)(y+1)}=\\
=\frac{(\sqrt{y}-1)\Big(\sqrt{y}(y+\sqrt{y}+1)-3)\Big)}{(\sqrt{y}-1)(\sqrt{y}+1)(y+1)}=\frac{\sqrt{y}(y+\sqrt{y}+1)-3}{(\sqrt{y}+1)(y+1)}\to0,y\to 1$$
2.
$$\frac{y-4\sqrt{y}+3}{y^2-1}=\frac{y-\sqrt{y}-3\sqrt{y}+3}{(y-1)(y+1)}=\\
=\frac{\sqrt{y}(\sqrt{y}-1)-3(\sqrt{y}-1)}{(\sqrt{y}-1)(\sqrt{y}+1)(y+1)}=\\
=\frac{(\sqrt{y}-1)\Big(\sqrt{y}-3)\Big)}{(\sqrt{y}-1)(\sqrt{y}+1)(y+1)}=\frac{\sqrt{y}-3}{(\sqrt{y}+1)(y+1)}\to -\frac 1 2,y\to 1$$


$\lim_{y\to 1}\frac{y^2-4\sqrt{y}+3}{y^2-1}$

I think that the official solution is wrong.  My computation is that the limit is $~0,~$ and I have double checked my analysis.
Rewrite the numerator as
$$(y^2 -4y + 3) + (4y - 4\sqrt{y}).$$

$$\lim_{y\to 1}\frac{y^2-4y+3}{y^2-1} 
= \lim_{y\to 1}\frac{(y-3)(y-1)}{(y-1)(y+1)}$$
$$= \lim_{y\to 1}\frac{y-3}{y+1} = \frac{-2}{2} = -1.$$

$$\lim_{y\to 1}\frac{4y - 4\sqrt{y}}{y^2-1}
= \lim_{y\to 1}\frac{4\sqrt{y} ~(\sqrt{y} - 1)}{(y+1) ~(\sqrt{y} - 1) ~(\sqrt{y} + 1)}$$
$$= \lim_{y\to 1}\frac{4\sqrt{y}}{(y+1) ~(\sqrt{y} + 1)} = \frac{4}{
4} = 1.$$
$$-1 + 1 = 0.$$

Both symbolab and wolframalpha gives the solution $-\frac{1}{2}$.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Limit%5BDivide%5BPower%5By%2C2%5D-4Sqrt%5By%5D%2B3%2CPower%5By%2C2%5D-1%5D%2Cy-%3E1%5D

@SineoftheTime Do you see a mistake in my analysis?

Your analysis is correct.  I get the same answer (below) using L'Hopital's Rule.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Limit%5BDivide%5By-4Sqrt%5By%5D%2B3%2CPower%5By%2C2%5D-1%5D%2Cy-%3E1%5D

@Sien you wrote $y$ instead of $y^2$ in the numerator

@user2661923 no, I don't find mistakes. Wolfram agrees that the limit is $0$ and that's the result obtained in all $4$ answers

SORRY, IT IS MEANT TO SAY $\lim_{y\to 1}\frac{y-4\sqrt{y}+3}{y^2-1}$

@Sien I suggest that you revert to posing the problem as $~y^2.~$ Once any MathSE reviewer gives an answer to the originally posted question, the original poster should never change the originally posted question.  Otherwise, you are asking the MathSE responder to hit a moving target.  My answer stands, because that is the problem that you originally posed.  Going forward, with your future MathSE questions, I suggest that you make more of an effort to proofread your question.

Shift the limit by performing the substitution $y-1=x$:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(x+1)^2-4\sqrt{1+x}+3}{x(x+2)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2+2x}{x(x+2)}-4\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-1}{x}\frac1{x+2}=1-1=0 $$
I used the property of the limits (limit of sum/product is the sum/product of the limits if they exist) and the following notable limit:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+x)^k-1}x=k $$
Edit
There was a typo and the limit is:
$$\lim_{y\to 1}\frac{y-4\sqrt y+3}{y^2-1}=\lim_{y\to 1}\frac{(\sqrt y-1)(\sqrt y-3)}{(y+1)(\sqrt y-1)(\sqrt y+1)}=\frac{-2}{2\cdot2}=-\frac12 $$

I'm trying to see why this does not match the OP's stated solution, but it isn't obvious.  Thoughts?

That's simply because the OP's answer is wrong. This is obvious when looked at graphically (Desmos).

Using L'Hopital's Rule, since the original fraction is in the form $\frac 00$:
$$\lim_{y \to 1} \frac{y^2-4 \sqrt y + 3}{y^2-1}= \lim_{y \to 1} \frac{2y-2/\sqrt y}{2y}= \frac{2-2}{2}=0.$$
Using L'Hopital's Rule on the corrected problem:
$$\lim_{y \to 1} \frac{y-4 \sqrt y + 3}{y^2-1}= \lim_{y \to 1} \frac{1-2/\sqrt y}{2y}= \frac{1-2}{2}=- \frac 12.$$

For the OP's problem:
$$\frac{y^2-4\sqrt{y}+3}{y^2-1}=\frac{y^2-1-4\sqrt{y}+4}{y^2-1}
=1-\frac{4(\sqrt y-1)}{y^2-1}
=1-\frac{4}{(y+1)(\sqrt y+1)}\to1-1=0.$$
If the problem is the following:
$$\frac{y-4\sqrt{y}+3}{y^2-1}=\frac{y-1-4\sqrt{y}+4}{y^2-1}
=\frac{1}{y+1}-\frac{4(\sqrt y-1)}{y^2-1}
=\frac{1}{y+1}-\frac{4}{(y+1)(\sqrt y+1)}\to\frac12-1=\frac{-1}2.$$

A trigonometric way with $y=\cos x \to 1$ and $x\to 0$
$$\lim_{y\to 1}\frac{y^2-4\sqrt{y}+3}{y^2-1}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos^2x-4\sqrt{\cos x}+3}{-\sin^2 x}=\lim_{x\to 0}4\frac{\sqrt{\cos x}-1}{x^2}\frac{x^2}{\sin^2 x}+1=0$$
indeed since $\cos x =1-\frac {x^2} 2+0(x^2) \implies \sqrt{\cos x}=1-\frac {x^2} 4+0(x^2)$
$$\frac{\sqrt{\cos x}-1}{x^2}=\frac{-\frac {x^2} 4+o(x^2)}{x^2}=-\frac14 +o(1)\to -\frac14$$
